# How can I set the key equivalent display for a menu item to more than one character?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an application which uses a key combination that is composed of more than one "normal" (non-meta) key, ex Command + Space + Right Arrow.  I trap this using special methods which works fine, but I want to display this key equivalent in a menu item to inform the user of its availability, ex:

```
DoSomething Cmd_>

(Command Space Right Arrow)
```

`NSMenuItem setKeyEquivalent` only accepts a single character, ex @" " for space, but i need to display more than one normal key equivalent in this field.

How can this be done?

Comment: Did you try setting a multiple-character string as the key equivalent?

Comment: Yes, multi-character strings are not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSMenuItem is extremely inflexible. You'd have to set a custom view on the menu item and draw the title, highlighting, animation, etc. yourself. Probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

It can't. The key equivalent for a menu item is a single keystroke or a keystroke with modifiers (Shift, Cmd, etc.) Chords (a series of independently pressed keys) are not supported by Cocoa.

What is it you're trying to accomplish? There may be another way to do it.

Comment: I am trying to provide some contextual help for my "chorded" key equivalent.. The menu item would remain disabled and be in the menu for help purposes only.